# Head First Android Development - RSS Feed

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm trying to learn Android and I downloaded a book named "Head First Android Development".

At some page I need to do a RSS Feed App using SAX.

This is my IotdHandler.java file: https://code.google.com/p/headfirstandroid/source/browse/trunk/HFA_Chapter_6/src/com/headfirstlabs/ch06/nasa/iotd/IotdHandler.java?r=6

And I get an error saying "can't resolve symbol "IotdHandlerListener" ".

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a listener class/interface defined as IotdHandlerListener.

Couldn't see that in imports. The IotdHandler cannot identify it from where it is declared.

Either you need to define/code it or import it, if already exists.

In using Eclipse, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to automatically arrange your imports.

Comment: I know that. I created the class manually and it kinda worked.

Comment: I get the same error! I created the class file manually and copy pasted the code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/headfirstandroid/source/browse/trunk/HFA_Chapter_6/src/com/headfirstlabs/ch06/nasa/iotd/IotdHandler.java?r=7). I arranged the imports too but no avail. I'm on Android Studio btw. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for IotdHandlerListener:

```
/**
 * IotdHandlerListener
 * 
 *  @author Geroen Joris - http://www.headfirstandroid.com/
 * 
 */

public interface IotdHandlerListener {

        public void iotdParsed(String url, String title, String description, String date);

}
```